# Mapping (potentiall nested) members in Typescript interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have some data that follows these interfaces, and I'm trying to produce a generic type mapper to use with [Pact](https://pact.io/).

```js
import { Matchers } from "@pact-foundation/pact";

interface Address {
  street: string;
  city: string;
  province: string;
  postalCode: string;
}

interface Person {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: Address;
}

type WrappedPact<Target> = {
  [Property in keyof Target]: Target[Property] | Matchers.MatcherResult;
};
```

This works fine for simple types like `Address`:

```js
type AddressPact = WrappedPact<Address>;
```

... but I get an error for `Person`:

```js
import { Matchers } from "@pact-foundation/pact";

type PersonPact = WrappedPact<Person>;

const personPact: PersonPact = {
  name: Matchers.string("Sam Smith"),
  age: Matchers.integer(42),
  address: {
    street: Matchers.string("123 Main Street"),
    city: Matchers.string("Anywhere"),
    province: Matchers.string("XX"),
    postalCode: Matchers.string("98765")
  }
};
```

Typescript complains about `personPact.address` since it is neither `Address | Matchers.MatcherResult`, which is true.

I can define `PersonPact` as:

```js
type PersonPact = WrappedPact<Omit<Person, "address">> & {
  address: WrappedPact<Person["address"]>;
};
```

... however I'd need to do this for every type that had any nested objects, which is cumbersome to say the least.

---

I tried updating `WrappedPact` to recursively wrap nested object types:

```js
type WrappedPact<Target> = {
  [Property in keyof Target]: Target[Property] extends Record<string, unknown>
    ?
        | Target[Property]
        | Matchers.MatcherResult
        | WrappedPact<Target[Property]>
    : Target[Property] | Matchers.MatcherResult;
};
```

... but my definition of `WrappedPact` is off, and I don't know quite what I need to fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar enough with Pact to know if this will work for all your use cases, but my inclination here would be to write `WrappedPact<T>` as:

```
type WrappedPact<T> = T extends object ? {
    [K in keyof T]: WrappedPact<T[K]>
} : T | Matchers.MatcherResult;
```

Here we are using a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html); if `T` is an object type, then `WrappedPact<T>` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) in which we wrap each property of `T` with `WrappedPact` recursively.  Otherwise, if `T` is not an object type, then `WrappedPact<T>` is `T | Matchers.MatcherResult`.

This produces the same result for your "simple" cases:

```
type AddressPact = WrappedPact<Address>;
/* type AddressPact = {
    street: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
    city: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
    province: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
    postalCode: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
} */
```

and also produces the desired result for objects with nested object properties:

```
type PersonPact = WrappedPact<Person>;
/* type PersonPact = {
    name: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
    age: number | Matchers.MatcherResult;
    address: {
        street: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
        city: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
        province: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
        postalCode: string | Matchers.MatcherResult;
    };
} */
```

and therefore your `personPact` object is assignable to `PersonPact`:

```
const personPact: PersonPact = {
    name: Matchers.string("Sam Smith"),
    age: Matchers.integer(42),
    address: {
        street: Matchers.string("123 Main Street"),
        city: Matchers.string("Anywhere"),
        province: Matchers.string("XX"),
        postalCode: Matchers.string("98765")
    }
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgWQIYwMYAsCmUDOcAvnAGZQQhwBEAAmKhjALSkQCuAdgCbrAScA9AybUA3AFgAUNOCcYeUoxxwAgt25Qc+QgmlwDcfDC04YALiMm5Ac0lTDcDMBgBPS8ai37jsBQBuchg4HtacdvqGkMaoADYAwhDcIVZe4fZE0rLyispwAAp4+AKIkQacqCApnt5lcKg2KZzsIABGeD6GqBpaOpbqmtr4GVlSbmAqAOpQqGAT3PmMMAA8ACoAfHAAvHCrcDgAHgo8hBCtAFY4THAA-KUOhgDaANJwcnAA1jiuEKS7ALqWaazeaLJhrF7-dbSEiWPYAHxQ6GwRQAdGhMLgoAAlbTsWIweyjaTjFQDXr4MHwHbAuY4BZLZbkobreyCABUcFJah6Qyp23ujk8ODMoTSNjgiIxKII6ORWNx+HxhLqzjcYtskqRmLR0oVeIJnQMfgggU4wQ14S1et18rwiuVRrg0RgcUSyUtEqldtlNpxBpVUhI7MExLGrgmBSKAn5NJmdIZ4MKBAErOkHK5EZUyeKnFjgsMFSqnutPvwcp1-qVhrqDSaLXaUFLlfLfodNYeBm6gz6BccBmFotSmu9LYrMvbgf7hjV7mHVtHMtbPsnTt8ASC1TCXu1S-H+urU+nzogMQSSS34ube7bAadRAycBDowwAmMzujeaWlhzMaWAr0Ts4CLFI-XLGpwgACmoABlSo4BgkAXCwagAEoABpa0aSwwNROQFEaKBIIAFgAJgw2teV7QDj1SEULF3LFwO3aCAEZSIAZiRd4YJMei0MwoDHFnHCy1RCCbGg1ROFcAB3LEcAEup11NTdRLHCToIADS0pShKiU9XXPD1GLRTTqAATgADgAdgANgAVjQupMiDMQgA)

Comment: It doesn't work with `Matchers.boolean`. For some reason an error is: `Type 'Matcher<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean | Matcher<false> | Matcher<true>'.`
See an example there: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/1054#issuecomment-1479463681